# Add a custom splash screen to WiX installer without Burn

Tags: wix

For my [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.6 based installer, I want to show a splashscreen before the welcome dialog. I did some searching, but it seems I can't find a clean solution.

How do I do this without using the [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bundle?

Comment: What do you mean by "splash screen?" In what way is the "welcome dialog" you mention not a splash screen?

Comment: Hey Tom. Basically I want an image show for a couple of seconds before the WIX welcome screen. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the Bundle, seems there is no built-in support for displaying a splashscreen. I ended up creating one using custom action and reorder the UI sequence.

```
      <InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="ShowSplashScreenAction" After="CostFinalize" ></Custom>
        <Show Dialog="PrepareDlg" After="ShowSplashScreenAction" >NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
      </InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: What was the Custom Action?  Can you share the `ShowSplashScreenAction` that you built with us?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a setup that calls an MSI, then do it in the setup.  It is far easier than doing it in WIX.  Just create a popup dialog, leave it on for a couple of seconds and that is it.  You can put on what you want and even make it configurable.  The really big advantage is that it will pop up before the .net framework installer.